# Change SQL statement Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, porting

I want to know how to change SQL statement from Oracle to SQL Server.
but, Error occurs

> Invalid syntax near keyword 'AS'

I don't know why error occurs.

```
SELECT A.DMND_NO
    , A.DMND_R_ID
    , C.EMP_NO
    , C.USER_NM
    , CASE WHEN C.TYPE_CD = '01' THEN C.DEPT_CD ELSE C.VENDOR_CD END AS DEPT_CD
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), A.ATH_DMND_DTM, 120) AS ATH_DMND_DTM
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), A.APRV_DTM, 120) AS APRV_DTM, A.APVR_ID
    , ISNULL(D.USER_NM, A.APVR_ID) AS APRV_NM
    , C.TYPE_CD
    , I.CODE_NM AS REQ_GB
FROM TB_SY_ATHDMND A RIGHT OUTER JOIN TB_SY_USER D
    ON A.APVR_ID = D.USER_ID
    , TB_SY_USER C RIGHT OUTER JOIN TB_SY_DEPT F
    ON C.DEPT_CD = F.DEPT_CD
    , TB_SY_ATHDMNDDET B
    , (SELECT COMP_CD, CODE_CD, CODE_NM FROM TB_SY_CODE WHERE CLS_ID = 'COM_CLS_0049' AND USE_CD = 'Y') I
WHERE A.DMND_NO = B.DMND_NO
    AND A.DMND_R_ID = C.USER_ID
    AND A.DMND_COMP_CD = I.COMP_CD
    AND C.TYPE_CD = I.CODE_CD
    AND A.PRGR_STAT_CD = '03'
    AND B.ATH_DVCD = 'U'           
 
    AND A.DMND_COMP_CD = #{gCOMP_CD}
<if test='SEARCHDT_FROM != null and !SEARCHDT_FROM.equals("") and SEARCHDT_TO != null and !SEARCHDT_TO.equals("")'>
    AND A.APRV_DTM BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), A.ATH_DMND_DTM, 112) AS ATH_DMND_DTM AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), A.APRV_DTM, 120) AS APRV_DTM
</if>          
<if test='TYPE_CD != null and !TYPE_CD.equals("")'>      
    AND C.TYPE_CD = #{TYPE_CD}
</if>
<if test='USER_NM != null and !USER_NM.equals("")'>      
    AND C.USER_NM = #{USER_NM}
</if>
ORDER BY A.APRV_DTM DESC, A.DMND_NO DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but did you try to use syntax like using one character space instead of AS ?

```
, CASE WHEN C.TYPE_CD = '01' THEN C.DEPT_CD ELSE C.VENDOR_CD END  DEPT_CD
, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), A.ATH_DMND_DTM, 120)  ATH_DMND_DTM
, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), A.APRV_DTM, 120)  APRV_DTM, A.APVR_ID
, ISNULL(D.USER_NM, A.APVR_ID)  APRV_NM
```

The syntax to ALIAS A TABLE in Oracle/PLSQL is:  table_name alias_name

AS is optional as you know.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are issues in two places in your code.

Extra `,` should be removed from the `FROM` clause

```
FROM TB_SY_ATHDMND A RIGHT OUTER JOIN TB_SY_USER D
    ON A.APVR_ID = D.USER_ID
    , TB_SY_USER C RIGHT OUTER JOIN TB_SY_DEPT F -- , at the start is not needed -- remove it
    ON C.DEPT_CD = F.DEPT_CD
    , TB_SY_ATHDMNDDET B -- , at the start is not needed -- remove it
    , (SELECT COMP_CD, CODE_CD, CODE_NM FROM TB_SY_CODE WHERE CLS_ID = 'COM_CLS_0049' AND USE_CD = 'Y') I -- , at the start is not needed -- remove it
```

`AS` should not be used in the `WHERE` clause conditions.

remove `AS ATH_DMND_DTM` and `AS APRV_DTM` from following code:

```
<if test='SEARCHDT_FROM != null and !SEARCHDT_FROM.equals("") and SEARCHDT_TO != null and !SEARCHDT_TO.equals("")'>
    AND A.APRV_DTM BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), A.ATH_DMND_DTM, 112) AS ATH_DMND_DTM AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), A.APRV_DTM, 120) AS APRV_DTM
</if>
```